# Protection from high voltage in high frequency ignition in plasma cutting machines

Tags: high-voltage, emc, high-frequency

I am currently in the process of designing a circuit for detection of a short circuit of a plasma cutter nozzle with material when there is no arc. The important requirement is that detection circuitry should also sustain the high frequency high voltage used to start the arc and continue operation of arc voltage.

[image]

The problem is as follows:

I want to do a continuity check between electrode and material when the arc is off.

It would be a relatively simple solution to connect small floating voltage source (V2) and reverse protection diodes (plasma current source is disconnected when there is no arc, so the electrode is high impedance but I have to protect the circuit from the plasma source when the arc is on.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWCK8h.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The high frequency causes problems. Below theoretical models of voltage between electrode and material during idle, ignition, and work.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmE3qR.png)</sup>

The circuit will be connected to the nozzle always. Due to design constraints I can't use a relay.

Concluding, my design goal is to remove the high frequency component (5-15kV, ~2MHz) and transient arc (like in cigarette lighter) and protect the comparator.

My first idea is to use LC filter for differential mode:

[image]

Please note that the circuits were simplified a bit. I would add a TVS diode as transient protection.

In simulation it seems to work, but is that an industry standard?

Maybe you have other ideas for effective filtration in such configuration.